# Google AppEngine conflict using Maven to compile with app.yaml in Codenvy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, pom.xml, app.yaml

My project configuration pom.xml contains:

```
<gae.version>1.8.6</gae.version>
```

And later on references the web.xml directly...

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
           <webResources>
              <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                 <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
              </resource>
           </webResources>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

....but my web.xml is empty because I'm using app.yaml to define my handlers.  Can I remove this plugin element without any consequences?  What about the maven-surefire-plugin?

Comment: Why are you using app.yaml?

Comment: It looks a little more straight forward syntax-wise than the web.xml (although I realize that's the industry standard).  GAE docs say they support it if it's there, even for Java apps.

...and to be honest, I wasn't sure how to specify static content folders in the web.xml.

Comment: Who do you mean when you say "We"?

... I only ask, because the GAE docs seem to encourage it: "With app.yaml, you can configure your Java application more easily, and with fewer files, than with the standard web.xml configuration."

Comment: Dave, I see you work for google on the GAE team.  Thanks for the reply.  Can you be more specific as to why web.xml is a better fit?  If it is indeed the team's thinking, then someone should update the docs to clarify, because now it encourages something you're discouraging as legacy.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this out of comments (and with the benefit of coffee).

A few reasons to prefer `appengine-web.xml` over `app.yaml` if you're working with Java.

1. You'll get better tooling support. This is a weak reason at the moment, but as the tooling around App Engine grows, `.xml` config will likely get the better support. I think you're running into one such case now.
2. If you're partially in the servlet world, or are working with people who are, `web.xml` is a norm.
3. My experience is that that using `app.yaml` limits your chances of getting help, because the pool of Java GAE users who also use `app.yaml` is small. Caveat: There's probably some sampling bias here.
4. If you think you might want to move off of App Engine some day, say, onto RedHat's [Cape Dwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf), I'm pretty sure they don't support `app.yaml`. (Not that it would be a huge change.)

That said, if you have a simple use case and `app.yaml` is working for you, stick with it. It is a supported option.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.